# Rails: ActiveRecord has_many association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm a bit new to Rails Active Record associations. I've tried to set up a relationship, but I get ActiveRecord error when I try to retrieve data. Did I associate my models incorrectly?

User has many Uploads, which has many UserGraphs:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :uploads, through: :user_graphs
end

class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :user_graphs
end

class UserGraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :upload
end
```

I want to get all of a user's uploads, and all of a user's graphs. The 2nd line doesn't work in rails console and gives an error

```
@user = User.find(1)
@uploads = @user.uploads
```

The error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :user_graphs in model User
```

**Extra Credit:**

If Users have Uploads that have UserGraphs... shouldn't it be `has_many :uploads` and `has_many :user_graphs, through :uploads`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
has_many :user_graphs
```

to the `User` and `Upload` classes.

The :through option defines a second association on top of this one.

Comment: Thanks @tyler - shouldn't it be has_many :user_graphs, through :uploads? Have I reversed it in my post's code?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell Rails that you have a `user_graphs` association on `User`, only an `uploads` association. So when Rails goes to follow the `user_graphs` association on `uploads`, it can't find it.

So, you need add the `user_graphs` association. Your models should look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_graphs                       # <<< Add this!
  has_many :uploads, through: :user_graphs
end

class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_graphs                       # <<< Add this!
  has_many :users, through: :user_graphs
end

class UserGraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :upload
end
```

Comment: Thanks @John! Great answer about what Rails is actually trying to do :)

Comment: Actually got a rails error - when I went to get user_graphs now. Error is about ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: graphs = User.find(1).uploads.user_graphs

Comment: Also the syntax in "User" model sounds strange. Wouldn't it be "has_many :uploads" and "has_many :user_graphs, through :uploads"?

Comment: @DonnyP: You can't do `user.uploads.user_graphs`, because "uploads" is a collection, and that collection doesn't have a `user_graphs` method on it. You would just do `user.user_graphs`.

Comment: Thanks @John - but it also seems like I've reversed my through statement. Shouldn't this be a "User" has_many "uploads". A "User" also has_many "user_graphs" through "uploads"?

Comment: @DonnyP: No, that's not right. The way you find the associated `Uploads` for a `User` is through a `UserGraph` entry. When you say `has_many :foos` on a class `Bar`, it means, "there should be a `bar_id` column on `Foo`". When you add `:through`, it means "the way you find this association is by looking at the specified table". In this case, the way you find the `uploads` is by looking at the `user_graphs` table: `has_many :uploads, :through => :user_graphs`.